# Understanding Spring AOP and Transaction Aspect

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions, spring-aspects

I was studying about the Proxy Object which spring gives when we autowire any interface. This is a very good link for understanding that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEvGdWjeCy4&t=310s. Here he explains that If a POJO implements any interface then Spring proxy bean also implements that interface (using JDK Proxy mechanism) and adds additional logic such as transactional logic (if the method was annotated using jdbc code or delegating it to PlatformTransactionManager). Spring gives us a wrapper object which has the reference to the real object and it has additional code which it runs before and after the original method is invoked using MethodInvocationHandler. So My question is that how exactly spring is managing that transaction.Where that jdbc code to get connection and start transaction is written. Is it in the Spring Proxy object or any Aspect Class.

As in AOP there as Aspects which are basically the cross cutting concerns such as transaction common to the whole application. Is Spring inserting Transaction behavior code in the Proxy Object or is it Using PlatformTransactionManager to do that And Where does This AOP fits in this Flow. How the Aspect handling Transactional behavior getting invoked here if it is. How the call is getting transferred to it?

Comment: I suggest you go through the Spring documentation section : [Transaction Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction) and [Understanding the Spring Framework’s Declarative Transaction Implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained)

Answer (score 0):

In term of JDK proxy , you have to supply a `InvocationHandler` implementation when creating a proxy object. When the proxy object is invoked ,  this `InvocationHandler` will be invoked around the actual object.  (see [this](https://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jdk-dynamic-proxies) for a hello world example for how does JDK proxy works)

In term of the spring transaction , it already shipped with an `InvocationHandler` implementation (i.e. `JdkDynamicAopProxy`). It will then somehow invoke the transaction aspect (i.e. `TransactionInterceptor`).  The transaction aspect is responsible for controlling the whole workflow such as when to create , commit or rollback the transaction and when to actually execute the actual method etc.

The transaction aspect also delegates to the `PlatformTransactionManager` to actually start , commit and rollback a transaction. Because different technologies has their own ways to start , commit and rollback a transaction , it is necessary to introduce a PlatformTransactionManager as an interface to abstract these operations such that we can switch different transaction technology by simply switching the `PlatformTransactionManager` implementation inside the transaction aspect .

So back to your questions :

> Where that jdbc code to get connection and start transaction is
> written. Is it in the Spring Proxy object or any Aspect Class.

None of them. It is actually the `PlatformTransactionManager` to get the connection and start the transaction which is invoked by the aspect.

> Is Spring inserting Transaction behaviour code in the Proxy Object or
> is it Using PlatformTransactionManager to do that And Where does This
> AOP fits in this Flow.

Spring inserts the transaction behaviour in the aspect object (i.e. `TransactionInterceptor`). The aspects then delegate to the `PlatformTransactionManager` to actually start , commit and rollback the transaction.

> How the Aspect handling Transactional behaviour getting invoked here
> if it is. How the call is getting transferred to it?

Assuming the JDK proxy is used , the call flow is something like :

1. Someone invokes on the JDK proxy
2. `InvocationHandler` of this proxy will be invoked (i.e `JdkDynamicAopProxy`)
3. `InvocationHandler` somehow calls spring transaction aspect  (i.e `TransactionInterceptor`)
4. Transaction aspect delegates to `PlatformTransactionManager` to actually start , commit and rollback the transaction if necessary.